# What does it mean to use scope during creation of a Rails record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

In the docs for explaining [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) what does calling the scope twice in the example below do? The first sets is like `Article.new('published': true)` but what does the 2nd `published` do?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end

Article.published.new.published    # => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `.published` isn't a scope, it's just getting the `:published` attribute from the new Article object. The code works like this:

1. The first `:published` is called on `Article` and returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object
2. Then `:new` is called on that ActiveRecord::Relation object ([Docs for ActiveRecord::Relation#new](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-new])) which returns a new `Article` that maintains the current scope (which in our case is like calling `Article.new(published: true)`)
3. The second `:published` just gets the published attribute from our new Article, which has been set to `true`

Comment: @stackjlei Did that help clarify your question? If so, do you mind checking my answer :)